# how to load a file in fundamental mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

When loading a file in emacs (via find-file), emacs loads the file into a buffer with the appropriate mode, invoking the appropriate handlers, etc. Sometimes, for debugging, I would like to be able to load a file directly into fundamental mode, without triggering anything else. What is the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Although it's a great question, something I had been wondering about and wanting to ask for a long time, but isn't it off-topic? [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would have been appropriate.

Comment: there's also now an [Emacs StackExchange site](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find-file-literally` is one answer.  But depending on what you need, `find-file-noselect` might be more appropriate.  Read the doc for each carefully (`(elisp) Visiting Functions`), and perhaps even look at their code, before deciding what is appropriate for your use.

Answer (score 11):

Use `find-file-literally`. Answer is 30 chars min.